# Why comparing text in google sheets returns true and false?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google Sheets table with input1 and input2 and curiously, comparing the text, the output returned `TRUE` and `FALSE` ! **How is the output determined?**

*Does Google Sheets like dogs more than cats?*

| **Input1** | **Input2** | **Output** | **FORMULATEXT** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Dog | FALSE | =A2>B2 |
| Dog | Cat | TRUE | =A3>B3 |
| Dog | Dog | FALSE | =A4>B4 |
| Dog | Dog | FALSE | =A5>B5 |
| Cat | Cat | FALSE | =A6>B6 |
| Cat | Dog | FALSE | =A7>B7 |
| Dog | Cat | TRUE | =A8>B8 |
| Dog | Cat | TRUE | =A9>B9 |
| Dog | Cat | TRUE | =A10>B10 |
| Cat | Dog | FALSE | =A11>B11 |

Comment: its based on alphabetic ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each character is checked against another, one by one.

In case of `Dog` vs `Cat`, the first character is checked and if it is greater based on [lexicographic-ordering](/questions/tagged/lexicographic-ordering)(Which maybe based on `CODE`), returns `TRUE` and no more checking is performed. If however, they're both the same character, next character is taken and compared: `Dog`>`Dng`. Here, `D` is the same, so `o` is compared against `n` and if  they're equal, goes to the next character and so on.

All the code of characters isn't summed. For eg,

```
="D">"CZZZZZ"
```

will always return `true` regardless of the number of `Z` after the first `C`, because `D` is greater than `C`